# Appium Inspector doesn't fit the screen (I can't see a part of the screen...)

Tags: ios, appium, appium-ios

JSON Representation is here.

```
{
  "platformName": "ios",
  "appium:platformVersion": "15.0.1",
  "appium:deviceName": "iPhone 13",
  "appium:bundleId": "com.kakaoenterprise.kakaowork",
  "appium:automationName": "XCUITest",
  "appium:udid": "00008110-001479340A0A801E"
}
```

Appium Inspector Screen:

[image]

Real Device Screen:

[image]

As you see, I cannot see part of the screen. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem.
I'm not sure, but it was normalized after reinstalling WDA. Please keep that in mind!